# New Unity AI Navigation window does not show the "Bake" option

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-editor

I have been using the "old" Navigation system in my project and have recently upgraded to a version of unity (2022.3.16f1) which comes with the latest AI.Navigation package.

I am keen to upgrade but am running into many problems.
I've added a NavMeshSurface to the floor gameobject and tried to bake directly from the component :

[image]

The result is poor, some objects that where previously tagged a non walkable are now walkable.
I tried the "new" navigation window but it does not show the "bake" and "object" options...

[image]

However the obsolete windows still works and bakes fine :

[image]

I'm wondering what I am doing wrong ?
Should I have first deleted something before creating the NavMeshSurface, why is the new navigation AI not showing me the Bake and Object options ?

Comment: because as shown above its on your navmesh surface now... not a window

Comment: So how do I define what objects are walkable, non walkable etc... ? I've tried to look at recent tutorials and they all use a "new" navigation windows. But maybe these tutorials are too old ?